# Powershell - find string starting with substring in array of stirngs

Tags: powershell

Lets say I have an array of strings:

```
$array = @('foo','bar','mega_foobar')
```

I am looking for a way to find a sting starting with `mega` in this array without iterating (looping) over it. Is this possible?

(something like this would be perfect)

```
$my_value = $array -Find 'mega*'
```

Comment: Try this: `$my_value = $array -Like 'mega*'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it is as simple as:

```
$my_value = $array -Like 'mega*'
```